# How to associate two tables based on a unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables I want to join in SQL Server.

One houses call data and has a unique id `Login_ID`. This table does not contain the employees name.

The other table does not have a unique id for employees.

What I need to do is join these two tables so I can see call data and ticket data simultaneously by employee.

Unfortunately, there is no correlating column for `Login_ID` in the ticket table to link employee data.

Example of call data table:

```
Login_ID | Calls | CallTime | Date   |
00000001 |  34   |  349874  | 030317 |
```

Example of ticket table:

```
Name     | Ticket_Num | Date   |
Some Emp | 5456465434 | 030317 |
```

So what happens is: anytime someone changes their name, they basically have a new ID in this table. It's awful.

I only need the data from around 18 employees.

My question is: how can I associate the `Login_ID` with the ticket table?

Hopefully I made this clear enough!

Comment: This sounds impossible to do retrospectively, unless the `Ticket_Num` is somehow a function of the `CallTime` or the like. Do you want to solve this for future queries only?

Comment: Please more DDL & tags, less redundant natural language.

Comment: You set up a foreign key between them. See my answer.

Comment: That result cannot be calculated from your input. Please be clearer about whether you are asking about what else you need to be given, or what possible ways you could deduce as much as you can from the particular data in the tables and how the world works, or what.

Comment: I don't see any data that provides an association between the tables. It appears that you don't have enough information to associate the two. Unless you have a Login_ID / Name table that you forgot to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to store the association using what is known as a [Foreign Key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp). This will ensure the integrity of the relationships between your data and can help optimize your queries when you are trying to pull associated data from different tables.

> A FOREIGN KEY is a key used to link two tables together.
>
> A FOREIGN KEY is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that
>   refers to the PRIMARY KEY in another table.
>
> The table containing the foreign key is called the child table, and
>   the table containing the candidate key is called the referenced or
>   parent table.

You get query associated date using a `join`.

If you have a 1:1 relationship you add `Login_ID` as a field to your ticket table and you can join your table on `Login.Login_ID = Tickets.Login_Id`.

```
Alter Table Tickets
    Add Login_ID int not null Constraint "FK_Tickets_LoginId" References Tickets(Login_Id)

// USAGE:
Select * from Logins Join Tickets on Logins.Login_ID=Tickets.Login_Id where Login_ID=@LoginId
```

If you can't modify either table then you can create a new table, perhaps `Logins2Tickets` which will contain two fields `Login_ID` and `Ticket_Num`

You can then join your `Logins` to `Logins2Tickets` on `Login.Login_ID = Tickets.Login_Id` and join `Logins2Tickets` to `Tickets` on `Logins2Tickets.Ticket_Num = Tickets.Ticket_Num`

```
Create Table Logins2Tickets
(
   Login_ID int not null constraint "FK_Logins2Tickets_Login_ID" References Logins(Login_Id)
   Ticket_Num bigint not null constraint "FK_Logins2Tickets_Ticket_Num" References Tickets(_Login_ID)
)

// USAGE:
Select * 
    From 
    Logins l Join Logins2Tickets lt 
        on l.Login_ID=lt.Login_ID 
    Join Tickets t 
        on lt.Ticket_Num=t.Ticket_Num 
    WHERE Login_ID=@LoginId
```

Comment: A FK per se is not needed. What is needed is for an association/relationship/table/relation on appropriate name-user_id pairs to be derivable from the given ones. A FK just tells the DBMS that values somewhere appear somewhere else, when/if that is so, for integrity & optimization.

Comment: Agreed. Changed my wording from "need" to "should". For inexperienced developers working with data I would highly recommend it even if for nothing else but to enforce data integrity.

Comment: What is going on is that *different tables* with *sufficient data* are needed. If query rows are specified in terms of base table meanings then *constraints are irrelevant*. Constraints are needed to query only when query rows are not specified in terms of base table meanings but those constraints imply that the query rows are the same rows that we can specify in terms of base table meanings. Eg If we want programmer names when only given employee names then it helps to know that programmers are employees. So mentioning FKs when querying is actually misleading.

Comment: You have totally lost me. The problem is there is a table with a login id. which is associated with a name. That name is stored in the tickets table to associate the two. But name is mutable and as he will soon find out non-unique. So Mary Smith gets married and changes here name to Mary Jones. The relation between the tables is now lost. While he doesn't "need" a foreign key he certainly needs a unique identifier for each table to associate the two. A key will enforce uniqueness. A Foreign key will enforce integrity preventing orphaned records from invalid changed deleted or inserted values.

Comment: The problem is there is a table with a login id. which is *not* associated with a name *by given data*--'there is no correlating field for "Login_ID" in the ticket table to link employee data;. So it is not known what name-login_id pair belongs to a person. We *need* sufficient pairs to match all Call user_Ids with all their Ticket names. If there were an explicit pair table, as long as a pairs table contains all *those* user_Id-name pairs, it doesn't matter whether there are extra Call user_ids, pair User_ids, Ticket names or pair names. Ie it doesn't matter whether there are FDs.

Comment: ("add Login_ID as a field" requires *more data*.) PS My comments about FDs in querying are independent of this particular question. My point is that people are taught that FDs are needed for querying, but they aren't. It's just that if you *have* a FD, you often join on it. But it doesn't matter whether one column set's value set is a subset of another's, you can still meaningfully join, and indeed the join returns the set of rows satisfying the same ciriteria, it's just that naturally if the input happens to be constrained by inclusion then the output is constrainted in a certain way too.

Comment: Thank you for spending so much effort helping with this issue. Unfortunately, I do not have access to alter any of the tables. I apologize for my lack of DDL and Tags; I'm still learning. In any case, my first thought was to create a temporary table with the name/Login_ID pairs and use that to associate the login_id with the names in the ticket table (still problematic) and the name with the Login_ID in the call table.

Comment: As stated you can create an entirely separate table, such as Logins2Tickets,  to keep track of the pairs. I would make it a permanent table and provided an example on how to do that while defining the foreign keys. As philipxy points out you don't _need_ the foreign keys but in practice I always use them as it prevents headaches.